# AndEngine MenuScene - can't click on Button

Tags: android, andengine

I have a small problem with android & andengine.
This is my source code of my main menu

```
// AbstractScene is extending Scene
public class MainMenuScene extends AbstractScene implements
        IOnMenuItemClickListener {
    private static final int MENU_CREATE = 10;
    private static final int MENU_JOIN = 20;
    private static final int MENU_ABOUT = 30;
    private static final int MENU_SETTINGS = 40;

    MenuScene scene;

    @Override
    public void loadResources() {
        res.loadMenuResources();
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        // Background
        setBackground(new Background(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));
        // Buttons
        scene = new MenuScene(res.camera);
        //scene.setPosition(GameActivity.WIDTH_CENTER, GameActivity.HEIGHT_CENTER);

        final SpriteMenuItem createGameMenuItem = new SpriteMenuItem(
                MENU_CREATE, res.createRegion, res.vbom);
        final SpriteMenuItem joinGameMenuItem = new SpriteMenuItem(MENU_JOIN,
                res.joinRegion, res.vbom);
        final SpriteMenuItem aboutMenuItem = new SpriteMenuItem(MENU_ABOUT,
                res.aboutRegion, res.vbom);
        final SpriteMenuItem settingsMenuItem = new SpriteMenuItem(
                MENU_SETTINGS, res.settingsRegion, res.vbom);

        scene.addMenuItem(createGameMenuItem);
        scene.addMenuItem(joinGameMenuItem);
        scene.addMenuItem(aboutMenuItem);
        scene.addMenuItem(settingsMenuItem);

        scene.buildAnimations();
        scene.setBackgroundEnabled(false);
        scene.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        setChildScene(scene, false, true, true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClicked(MenuScene pMenuScene, IMenuItem pMenuItem,
            float pMenuItemLocalX, float pMenuItemLocalY) {
        Log.d("Menuitem", "click");
        switch (pMenuItem.getID()) {
        case MENU_CREATE:
            return true;
        case MENU_JOIN:
            SceneManager.getInstance().showScene(SceneType.LISTGAMES);
            return true;
        case MENU_ABOUT:
            return true;
        case MENU_SETTINGS:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my code from the ResourceManager

```
// menu ressources
public void loadMenuResources() {
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    menuAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(activity.getTextureManager(),
            1024, 1024, BitmapTextureFormat.RGBA_8888, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    createRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(menuAtlas, activity.getAssets(), "btn_create_game.png");
    joinRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(menuAtlas, activity.getAssets(), "btn_join_game.png");
    settingsRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(menuAtlas, activity.getAssets(), "btn_settings.png");
    aboutRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(menuAtlas, activity.getAssets(), "btn_about.png");

    try {
        menuAtlas.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 0, 0));
        menuAtlas.load();
    } catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error while loading menu resources", e);
    }
}
```

My problem is, that the `OnMenuItemClickListener` is not called and i don't know why. The most code is copied from the official example. My app shows the background menus button etc but i cant click at one.

Does anybody knows why? Thx!

Comment: just curious why are you calling setChildScene here?

Comment: Because my Scenemanager, which calls this MainMenu use the attachChild. After that i have to use Setchild, or?

Comment: ok, sorry - may be I'm just misreading it - it's been a while since I messed with AndEngine, but looking at my code, I never call that.

Comment: Well, i can repleace it with `attachChild` but the problem is the same :/

Comment: @Tobias Do you get an error at all?

Comment: Nope there are no errors ;)

Comment: @Tobias When you try touching one of the menu buttons, does anything show up in the log (that is, as a result of `Log.d("Menuitem", "click");`)?

Comment: Nope there are no results ;) the buttons are shown correctly but i can't touch them ^^

Comment: check if you're calling `pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(scene);`

Comment: I haven't touch Andengine code in a while, but have you  register a Touch Area? If my memory is right, something like `scene.registerTouchArea(sprite);`

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a register touch area call

```
 scene.registerTouchArea(createGameMenuItem);
 scene.registerTouchArea(joinGameMenuItem);
 scene.registerTouchArea(aboutMenuItem);
 scene.registerTouchArea(settingsMenuItem);
```

Comment: no menuscene doesn't require registrig touch area. I have working code without toucharearegistring.

Comment: That's right! What if you try not to modal your child scene ? 'setChildScene(scene, false, false, false);'

Comment: IDK sorry, but eventually I found that the reason for not working in my code(I had same question, which is actually solved by now with newer andengine version)  and OP's code is different(older andengine probably).

Comment: why don't you ask the OP for trying that? :D