# Android Touch not working. Andengine

Tags: android, touch, andengine

The scene is made pretty well but the touch is not working. I registered all sprites and made `onTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true)` too. I have tried using Andengine's made in `MenuScene` but it is not working touching part only too. Here's my present code.
I had same problem as this gentleman [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250067/andengine-menuscene-cant-click-on-button), since I had no way out I changed my code to:

```
import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion;
import org.andengine.opengl.util.GLState;
import org.andengine.opengl.vbo.VertexBufferObjectManager;

import com.***.RM;           //I changed the directory name to ***
import com.***.SceneManager; //I changed the directory name to ***
import com.***.SceneType;    //I changed the directory name to ***

public class MainMenuScene extends BaseScene {

    private final int MENU_PLAY = 0;
    private final int MENU_OPTIONS = 1;
    private final int MENU_CREDITS = 2;
    private final int MENU_EXIT = 3;

    final int w = 256, h = 64;

    public class MenuSprite extends Sprite {

        private int ID;

        public MenuSprite(int pID, int pX, int pY, ITextureRegion tex, VertexBufferObjectManager vbom) {
            super(pX, pY, w, h, tex, vbom);
            this.ID = pID;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            System.out.println("text");
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown() || pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()) {
                onclick(this.ID);
                this.setScale(1.5f);
                return true;
            } else {
                this.setScale(1f);
            }

            return true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void createScene() {
        attachChild(new Sprite(RM.MX, RM.MY, rM.menu_back, vbom) {
            @Override
            protected void preDraw(GLState pGLState, Camera pCamera) {
                super.preDraw(pGLState, pCamera);
                pGLState.enableDither();
            }
        });

        final MenuSprite playMenuItem = new MenuSprite(MENU_PLAY, RM.MX, RM.CH * 4 / 6, rM.menu_play, vbom);
        final MenuSprite optionsMenuItem = new MenuSprite(MENU_OPTIONS, RM.MX, RM.CH * 3 / 6, rM.menu_options, vbom);
        final MenuSprite creditsMenuItem = new MenuSprite(MENU_CREDITS, RM.MX, RM.CH * 2 / 6, rM.menu_credit, vbom);
        final MenuSprite exitMenuItem = new MenuSprite(MENU_EXIT, RM.MX, RM.CH * 1 / 6, rM.menu_exit, vbom);

        attachChild(playMenuItem);
        attachChild(optionsMenuItem);
        attachChild(creditsMenuItem);
        attachChild(exitMenuItem);

        registerTouchArea(playMenuItem);
        registerTouchArea(optionsMenuItem);
        registerTouchArea(creditsMenuItem);
        registerTouchArea(exitMenuItem);

        setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void disposeScene() {
    }

    @Override
    public SceneType getSceneType() {
        return SceneType.SCENE_MENU;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackKeyPressed() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void onclick(int ID) {
        switch (ID) {
            case MENU_PLAY:
                SceneManager.getInstance().createLevelSelectionScene();
                break;
            case MENU_OPTIONS:
                break;
            case MENU_EXIT:
                onBackKeyPressed();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Here's a screenshot(I removed the title):
[image]

In Logcat I get the following on touching:

```
04-02 22:29:31.909: I/InputReader(159): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0
04-02 22:29:31.909: I/InputDispatcher(159): Delivering touch to current input target
```

but my application filtered messages have no touch log, not even the `system.out` that I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(menuScene);` is not present.

This does not give any warnings or errors but creates problems.